# what is wrong with this code

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

```
class MyClass {

    private $db;

    // Constructor 
    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'Test_db');
        $this->db->autocommit(FALSE);
    }

    // Destructor 
    function __destruct() {
        $this->db->close();
    }

    // Main method 
    function MyFun() {

        // Check for required parameters
        if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]) && isset($_POST["email"])) {
        echo "Before \n";
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $activation = 0;
        echo "After \n";
            // tracking 
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, username, password, email,activation) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("is", $name, $username, $password, $email, $activation); //Line 95
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();

        }
```

**Output:**

Before

After

Invalid request

**MAMP Console:**

```
[15-Apr-2011 15:09:10] PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [<a href='function.mysqli-stmt-bind-param'>function.mysqli-stmt-bind-param</a>]: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Test/reg.php on line 95
```

The number is the same but I don't know why this error appears

Comment: `Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variable`

Comment: Do you really use to comment `// Constructor` your class costructors?

Comment: @DaNiel : what is the problem yes I COMMENT everywhere in my code BTW this is my first code in MYSQL

Comment: take it easy mate, i was kiddin! Just pointing that `// Constructor` is a bit useless without some info (for example, the arguments and some operation it does).

Peace&Love ;)

Comment: @DaNiel: Your Welcome dude, always Peace&Love. But as I told you before this is my first MYSQL code and I am a little bit confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$stmt->bind_param("is", $name, $username, $password, $email, $activation);
```

Your "definition" string ("is") contains only two definitions, integer and string ... you should have 5 in there.

```
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $name, $username, $password, $email, $activation);
```

... for example ...

Answer (score 2):

You are only having five `?` placeholders in your query, yet you're trying to bing six values to the query.
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $name, $username, $password, $email, $activation);

1. "is"
2. $name
3. $username
4. $password
5. $email
6. $activation

The format you are giving does only contain 2 definition, yet it must contain 5 to match your query. Try `"sssss"`.

Comment: Nope, he is binding five values. But there are too few format characters in `is`, it should be `issss` (or whatever the format of each field is)

Comment: @Pekka, indeed. Adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The "is" is the sixth variable, I suggest you remove this or add the field name in the statement:

```
$stmt->bind_param("is", $name, $username, $password, $email, $activation);
```

Either remove from bind_param:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, username, password, email,activation) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param($name, $username, $password, $email, $activation);
```

or add to field names:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (**is**, name, username, password, email,activation) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("**is**", $name, $username, $password, $email, $activation);
```

or
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, username, password,
    email,activation) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("issss", $name, $username, $password, $email, $activation);